# Is this silk layer for isolation or is there any other use of this type of design?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, analog, digital-communications

[image]

In one of the bsttery management systems, I found this arrangement on PCB. I am confused by this arrangement.  Is it for isolation or is there any other use?

Comment: I wonder if "BC" could mean "battery contact", perhaps used for testing the BMS at the factory.

Comment: Yes, these JST terminal points are an intermediate nodes of the li-ion battery pack.

Comment: Might just be to make it easy to find visually on the board.